# WPF MediaElement not playing video when application is started from .exe

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've set a MediaElement with a video as window background for my application. It works, but only when I start the program from Visual Studio. If I try to start it from the builded .exe, the video in MediaElement won't load and the background remains black.
This is my code:

```
<Window.Background >
    <VisualBrush>
        <VisualBrush.Visual>
            <MediaElement Source="Resources/BF4R.wmv" LoadedBehavior="Play" IsMuted="True" MediaEnded="BGRAIN_MediaEnded" ></MediaElement>
        </VisualBrush.Visual>
    </VisualBrush>
</Window.Background>
```

and these are BF4R.wmv properties:

Build Action: Content

Copy to Output Directory: Copy always

Comment: Is there a `Resources/BF4R.wmv` next to the executable.

Comment: No. It wasn't, now it works. But I wanted it to play from embedded resource. How can I do that?

Comment: Use as `Resource` instead of `Embedded resource` and use `Pack URI` to identify the resource.

Comment: I tried `Source="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Resources/BF4R.wmv"` and it remains black but in designer the background is shown.

Comment: `siteoforigin` mean that you have deployed your application from internet resource and you try to download resource from it.

Comment: And how should it be? I'm new to WPF and I dont know a lot about resources and XAML.

Comment: This is good explanation of [Pack URI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

When a local application can access a particular resource, but an installed version cannot, there are normally just a few possible reasons:

1) The resource was not deployed correctly:

To ensure that resources are deployed, you should generally set their *Build Action* to *Content* and *Copy to Output Directory* to *Copy always*. I see that you have done this. If you are using the *Publish* tab of the project's *Properties* page to publish your application, then verify that your resource is listed and set to *Include* in the *Application Files* dialog window by clicking on the related button.

2) The resource cannot be reached by file path when the application is deployed:

It is good practice to use the following format of file path (from the [Pack URIs in WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN):

> The following example shows the pack URI for a XAML resource file that is located in a subfolder of the referenced assembly's project folder.

```
pack://application:,,,/ReferencedAssembly;component/Subfolder/ResourceFile.xaml
```

So in your case, this would be more like:

```
Source="pack://application:,,,/YourAssemblyName;component/Resources/BF4R.wmv"
```

Comment: I tried this. It works in designer but at run time the media element remains black.